# Creating Alertbox as a separate widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

What my objective is to create the Alertbox whenever the user clicks on logout. Since there are many pages where the logout button is presented, to avoid code duplication I'm making the alertbox as a separate widget. I'm having issues with context. I'm aware widgets work on Context. How can I work around the issue, when the alertbox to be treated as a separate widget?

```
 final AuthService _auth = new AuthService();
    
    class Signout {
      changeRoute(String choice) {
        if (choice == "Ausloggen") {
          return showDialog(
            context: context, // Undefined name 'context'.
            barrierDismissible: true,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Container(
                    child: Icon(
                  Icons.warning_rounded,
                  size: Sizes.s40,
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                )),
                content: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
                  child: Text(
                    'Sind Sie sicher?',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: Sizes.s20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to provide a context from the outside. Like this:

```
class Signout {
  changeRoute(BuildContext context, String choice) {
    if (choice == "Ausloggen") {
      return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Container(
                child: Icon(
              Icons.warning_rounded,
              size: Sizes.s40,
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
            )),
            content: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
              child: Text(
                'Sind Sie sicher?',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: Sizes.s20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

And then, when you will call it you should provide an appropriate context:

```
Signout.changeRoute(context, 'myChoice');
```

Comment: the choices are mapped on  itemBuilder.  and the Signout.chageRoute is on onSelected. How can i then pass the values of itembuilder as choice to onSelected?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Could you provide more info/code?

Comment: @ChessMaxPopupMenuButton(
                        onSelected: Signout.changeRoute(context, 'myChoice'), // how can i pass actionMap 
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return actionMap
                              .map(
                                (e) => PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: e,
                                  child: Text(e),
                                ),
                              )
                              .toList();
                        },
                    )

Comment: PopupMenuButton(
     onSelected: (value) => Signout.changeRoute(context, value),
     itemBuild: ...
    );